# Show number of items, but hide paging?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I want to show the 'Show "5" entries', and allow the user to change the number of entries shown, but I want to hide the 'paging' bit (By default, under the table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table_recent').DataTable(
    {
        "paging": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "filter": false,
        "pageLength": 5,
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]]

    });
});
```

Setting paging to false, removes both the drop down and the pages. Is there a way to display only the pages at the bottom?

i.e:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_recent').DataTable(
        {
            "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"l><"clear">',
            "ordering": false,
            "pageLength": 5,
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]]

        });
    });
</script>
```

It's the dom thing. Not sure how the syntax works. Some trial and error and I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Add following

```
"bLengthChange": false,
```